# What is the difference in using Nous allons à la pêche sur dimanche and Nous allons à la pêche le dimanche

Tags: grammaire, prépositions

What is the difference in using  Nous allons à la pêche sur dimanche and   Nous allons à la pêche le dimanche.

Comment: Un moyen de savoir que « Sur dimanche » est incorrect : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=le+dimanche%2Csur+dimanche&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3

Comment: I did not understand it.

Comment: Il s'agit plus certainement de « p**ê**che » que de « p**è**che ».

Comment: *Ngram Viewer* vous indique en rouge que « sur dimanche » est utilisé ***zéro fois*** dans sa base de donnée “French (2019)”,  ce n'est donc pas une expression correcte.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Le + day of the week

To express usual or repeated activity on a day of the week, use *le* + the day of the week.  *Le dimanche* means every Sunday, or normally on Sundays, plural.

It is often translated as "On Sunday**s**, [we go fishing]" but *sur* is never used for "on" in this case.

### Day of the week

Using just the day of the week implies one time action.  "Dimanche nous allons à la pêche" means what we're doing this Sunday or on Sunday (note the singular).  It is almost the same as saying *ce dimanche.*

### Ce + day of the week

To specify "this Sunday" is *ce dimanche*.  As opposed to *le dimanche,* *ce dimanche* nous allons à la pêche means specifically this Sunday.

Answer (score 2):

As commented. the initially accepted answer is a lot for a beginner. First, **pèche** is not fishing, it is a conjugated form of either **pêcher** (to fish) or **pécher** (to sin).

As for fishing, it is **pêche** not **pèche**.

There is no *sur dimanche*, you can either say *le dimanche* or *ce dimanche*.

Answer (score 1):

You can't say "sur dimanche" at all in this context, it's incorrect. "Le dimanche" is correct.

"Sur" can be used to indicate when something occurs but in a limited type of situations. These situtions are listed below; however for one of them (time of day) this usage is old and rather rare.

*From the [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sur)*

> III. − [Empl. temp. ou temp.-causal]
> A. − [Sur introd. un compl. exprimant un repère temp.]
> 1. [Il marque la coïncidence, la concomitance (idée de recouvrement)]
> a) [Avec idée d'approximation]
> α) **[Le repère est l'heure]** Vieilli ou rare. Sur les huit heures.
> ► Elle osa sortir de la maison par une fenêtre du derrière, sur les onze heures, quand elle vit sa tante et son oncle profondément endormis (Stendhal, Lamiel, 1842, p. 134).
> ♦ Sur le coup de huit heures.
> ► Il s'agissait de faire une surprise à Maigret, qui téléphonait invariablement sur le coup d'onze heures (Simenon, Vac. Maigret, 1948, p. 102).
> β) **[Le repère est une division naturelle de la journée]**
> ► Des gelées ont eu lieu sur le matin. Et comme c'est demain dimanche, tu viendras voir ta mère sur le jour (Sand, Pte Fadette, 1849, p. 41).
> ► Sur le soir, des soldats arrivèrent (Barbusse, Feu, 1916, p. 103).
> ► Un dimanche d'octobre, sur le tantôt, une voiture attira soudain mon attention (R. Depestre, Hadriana dans tous mes rêves, 1988, p. 17).
> ♦ **Sur le/les midi**.
> ► J'irai vous voir vendredi prochain **sur les midi** (Balzac, Corresp., 1842, p. 506).
> ► J'aurais pourtant voulu que nous mangions de bonne heure de façon à partir **sur le midi** (Pourrat, Gaspard, 1922, p. 28).

Comment: Merci monsieur.

Comment: This is way over the top for a beginning level.

Comment: @Lambie Tous les exemples (►) sont du français de tous les jours, très courant qui ne peuvent faire que du bien à qui a un peu de curiosité. Personnellement je suis de l'avis de H D Thoreau: « In the long run men hit only what they aim at. Therefore, though they should fail immediately, they had better aim at something high.

Comment: **Du français de tous les jours ??** ROTFL. Only *sur le coup de onze heures* is everyday's French. None of the remaining *sur* quotes are in use nowadays.

Comment: @jlliagre On dit encore « sur les onze heures », « sur le soir » ; de toute façon il n'y a rien d'autre pour expliquer où on peut encore trouver « sur » dans ce contexte. De plus si on veut lire de la littérature qui a encore de l'intérêt (Stendhal, Simenon, Sand, Balzac et d'autres) il vaut mieux avoir une idée de ces usage qui font toujours partie du français.

Comment: Non, je suis désolé mais en France, personne ne dit plus *sur les onze heures* et encore moins *sur le soir*. La présence de *sur le tantôt* dans cette liste indique aussi un régionalisme.

Comment: @jlliagre En fait je crois que c'est utilisé pour signifier "vers" et je ne m'en sert pas mais ma propre mère (morte il y a une trentaine d'années) a utilisé les deux toute sa vie. Elle n'aurait jamais dit "Vers le soir il commence à faire frais." mais "Sur le soir…". En effet on ne trouve de traces de ces usages que dans une littérature déjà ancienne.