# Why the definitive article instead of the preposition (and vice versa) in these sentences?

Tags: prépositions, indications-de-temps, articles-definis

Sentence 1: "On a rendez-vous demain **à** midi."
Sentence 2: "Il préfère travailler **le** soir."

Why not "le midi" and "à soir", both with "le", both with "à" or even maybe even with "au"?

Next:
"Fermé le dimanche."
"Fermé jeudi prochain."

Is there no "le" in the second sentence because the "prochain" modifying it? Would that be a general rule or just with dates?

Thanks.

Comment: It's constructed nearly as in english : We meet tomorow at noon, He'd rather work in the evening.

Comment: Maybe this is a belgicism, but "le midi" is also used to qualify "around/at lunch time". Example: "Le midi je mange à la cantine, mais le soir je mange à la maison".

Answer (score 5):

With expressions of clock time, use the preposition **à** to say (at) what time.  You can leave out the "at" in English, but not the à in French.  It answers the question « À quelle heure ... ? »

> À quelle heure ?
> À midi. 
> Demain on a rendez-vous à 13h30.  
> On va dîner à
> 19h00.
>
>  Je me lève toujours à cinq heures.

For expressions of repeated days or times like le matin, le soir, or days of the week like le lundi, le mardi, **le** shows that it is a usual, repeated event.

> Le matin je me lève tôt.
> Le mercredi, on mange le déjeuner chez nous. 
> Je ne travaille pas le samedi.  Le samedi, le magasin est fermé.

Every morning, on Wednesdays, on Saturdays in general.  « Fermé le jeudi » follows this pattern.

To specify next Thursday, but not every Thursday, use « jeudi prochain. » It also means not this Thursday, but Thursday next.  That works with names for days of the week (not necessarily dates).

> On voulait partir en vacances samedi prochain.
>
>  Lundi prochain c'est un jour férié.

but

> L'année prochaine on va voyager.
>
>  Qu'est-ce qu'on va faire la semaine prochaine ?

Related [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/43301/1893)